# Problems with AJAX in jQuery and IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I had a real problem with Internet Explorer in all versions. I have some Ajax code using jQuery, and it works perfect in all the others browsers and the purpose is to return an alert with the message "Bienvenido", but doesn't work with Internet Explorer. Here I provide the code and the page in where you can try with the code and see.

```
function chargeFnc(mdlnm, btnm, scrnm, args){
    $.post(
        document.location, {md:mdlnm, bt: btnm, scr: scrnm},
        function(data){
            alert(1);
            $('#header_hd').append(data);
            $('#header_hd').load("#"+args[0], function(){
                execfnc(scrnm, args);
            });
        });
}
```

The web page it's [www.hidura.webfactional.com](http://www.hidura.webfactional.com)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but your JSON notation should be:

```
{'md':mdlnm, 'bt': btnm, 'scr': scrnm}
```

Also, a little more complete code would be helpful since you don't show what the execfnc() does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sorry i couldn't saw it because gmail put the mail in the junk i change the method i will use XML to send the data to the server. But thanks equal

Comment: No need to quote property names in JS. If you're serializing it to JSON, you should use double quotes, not single quotes.